# ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (64, 60, 1, 1) for Tensor 'targets/Y:0', which has shape '(?, 1, 1, 8)'

Tags: shapes, tensor

def autoencoder(.....):

```
model_name="..."

convnet = input_data(shape=[None,window,1,1], name='input')
convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 16, 3, activation='relu')
   .......

model.fit({'input': final_train},{'targets': real_final_train}, n_epoch=100,
          validation_set=({'input': final_validation},{'targets': real_final_validation}),
          show_metric=True, run_id=model_name)

model.save(model_name)
return model
```

The shape of inputs is (215, 60, 1, 1) with 215 is the number of samples